# Is threading.Event threadsafe?

Tags: python, multithreading

Is threading.Event threadsafe? Can I access an event safely by calling `Class.event.wait()`?

Example Code,

```
import threading
import time

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.startup_event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(4)
        print('Hello World')
        self.startup_event.set()


w = Worker()
w.start()
w.startup_event.wait()
print('%s started' % w.__class__.__name__)
```

Comment: Yes, it is. It's a synchronization primitive for this purpose exactly. Have a look [here](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/) for some examples.

Comment: @mfukar: Remember we are talking about a language that once included a [mutex that wasn't thread-safe](http://bugs.python.org/issue1746071) in their standard library.  But you are right `Event` objects are meant to be used with threads.